# Impersonation in app.config

Tags: vb.net, app-config, impersonation, credentials

I have been handed a desktop application, written in vb.  My task is to impersonate a given user for the entire application.  This is the first desktop application I've ever touched - I'm a web developer.

In app.config, I have done something like this, under system.web

identity  impersonate="true" userName="somedomain\someuser" password="somepassword"

She doesn't work.  This works fine in a similar web.config file for a completely different web application.  I returned WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name in vb, which just gave me my own username and domain (same domain, if that matters at all).

What else do I need to do to get her to work, or what could I be doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [`WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) It has an example of how to Impersonate a user, it does use some Windows API Functions though. Also you can look at this [`Code Project Article`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4863/LSA-Functions-Privileges-and-Impersonation).